# MATLAB code: Plot utility function and budget constraint

Tags: preferences, matlab

how do i plot these?
i have this utility function: $$U(x_1,x_2)=\log(x_1)+\beta \log(x_2)$$
and this budget constraint: $$p_1 x_1+p_2 x_2=R$$      where $R=3, p_1=0.5, p_2=0.5$
i dont know how to plot these so i can show the optimum point from $MRS=p_1/p_2$

this is my code:

```
clear all; clc; close all;
syms x1 x2 beta p1 p2 t x1_star x2_star

R=3; %disposable income
grid_points=100;
beta=1/3
p1=0.5;
p2=0.5;
t=0.25;
q_x1=p1+t %x1 quantity

maxX1=R/p1;
maxX2=R/p2;
maxX1_t=R/q_x1;


x1=linspace(0, maxX1, grid_points);
x2=(R-x1*p1)/p2; %budget constraint
plot(x1, x2, 'LineWidth',1);
hold on
x1_t=linspace(0, maxX1_t, grid_points);
x2_t=(R-x1_t*q_x1)/p2; %budget constraint
plot(x1_t, x2_t, 'LineWidth',1);


%optimal choices

syms x1 x2
%curve1

UU(x1,x2)=log(x1)+beta*log(x2);
SMS=diff(UU,x1)/diff(UU,x2)
% R=p1*x1+p2*x2
[x1_star,x2_star]=solve(p1*x1+p2*x2-R, (3*x2)/x1-p1/p2)

UU_1_star=UU(x1_star,x2_star)
UU_1_star=1.6392
X=solve(UU(x1,x2)==UU_1_star);
hold on
fplot(X)
ylim([0 6])
xlim([0 6])

%curve2

UU(x1,x2)=log(x1)+beta*log(x2);
[x1_star2,x2_star2]=solve(q_x1*x1+p2*x2-R, x2/(beta*x1)-q_x1/p2)
UU_2_star=UU(x1_star2,x2_star2)
UU_2_star=1.2338
X2=solve(UU(x1,x2)==UU_2_star);
fplot(X2)
```

As you can see i have problems plotting

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to Stackoverflow.

Comment: It's economics related

Comment: @Art I think this can stay according to our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Software questions: Questions related to software used in economics and econometrics, are on-topic here." This is clearly application of matlab to narrow economic problem

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to plot on the graph? When I run your code, it seemed to produce [something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSYFx.png) that shows a tangency.

Comment: the tangency point for the blue and yellow lines might be the marginal rate of substitution (MRS). He needs to say what he thinks is wrong about the graph